# Locally works fine, on server -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

When running my rails app locally, everything works fine. However, when deployed to a server, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (TasksController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.
```

It's similar for all the pages. What could be the problem?

Rails version is 5.0.1. The deployed application is running on unicorn and nginx. I'm using slim templates. The same problem appears either if the views have `.slim` extension or `.html.slim`.

Comment: slim is a gem? missing on server?

Answer (score 0):

The `slim` gem might not be installed on your server. Try running `bundle install` on the command line in your app directory and then restarting your server.